# Xpath does not capture the element even with the WebDriverWait

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to Selenium Testing and trying to locate the below input element using Xpath:

[image]

This is the username input element of the *https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login* website.

My code is:

```
private static final By USER_NAME_TEXT_BOX = By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='auth.username']");
private static final By PASSWORD_TEXT_BOX = By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='auth.password']");
private static final By LOGIN_BUTTON = By.xpath("//button[starts-with(@button, 'orangehrm-login-button')]");

private  LoginPage setUserNameTextBox(String userName) {
    PageActionsHelper.waitAndSendKeys(USER_NAME_TEXT_BOX,userName);
    return this;
}
```

and the PageActionsHelper.waitAndSendKeys() is as follows:

```
 public static void waitAndSendKeys(By by, String value) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 60);
        WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(by));

        //trigger the reaload of the page
        getDriver().findElement(by).sendKeys(value);
        // wait the element "Add Item" to become stale
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(element));
        // click on "Add Item" once the page is reloaded
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(by)).sendKeys(value);
        //getDriver().findElement(by).sendKeys(value);
    }
```

I also checked below:

1. Cannot find any **iframe** wrapped this element.
2. When I execute
   `$x("//input[@name='username']")` or
   `$x("//input[@placeholder='auth.username']")` in the web console, it
   locates correctly!
3. WebDriverWait does the waiting but empty
   browser is loaded and just timeout with the below exception:

[image]

I was using Safari browser and the screenshot was taken from it.
When I use Chrome developer option, labels are totally different. (Bit strange)

Answer (score 0):

When I open the link you shared I see somewhat different UI, the placeholder is different there, however I think the following locators should work for both cases:

```java
private static final By USER_NAME_TEXT_BOX = By.xpath("//input[@name='username']");
private static final By PASSWORD_TEXT_BOX = By.xpath("//input[@name='password']");
private static final By LOGIN_BUTTON = By.xpath("//button");
```

Comment: Thanks @Prophet I was using Safari when publishing the question, when i checked in Chrome, labels shown are totally different of how they shows in Safari developer tools. not sure the reason though.

Comment: Maybe. That's why we always should use fixed attributes. Placeholder may change while `name` attribute should be more fixed and stable

Comment: thanks @Prophet, I used your suggestion but I still get the below error even after a rebuilt:

*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//input[@name='username']}

Comment: Still NoSuchElementException?

Comment: yes it is. Any issue with time wait with element loading and locating?

Comment: Well, you didn't share ALL your Selenium code, so we can only guess. Maybe you are opening a new tab there but didn't switch to it?

Comment: so far, that is the only code I have written.